# Android Developer Tools do not recognize the newer API?

Tags: android, sdk, adt

The project was built on Android 4.4.2.

Now I want to use new APIs of Android 5.0.1.
The ADT do not recognize '`BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY`'.
How can I fix it?

[image: code like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the image provided it's clear that your build target is still set to Android 4.4.2, you need to change it to 5.0.1:
[image]

Also you really should migrate to using Android Studio by now, there's no telling how long will Google continue to support Eclipse ADT.

Comment: @sonichy no problem. if the answer helped you, please mark it as the correct answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should be sure that your compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion is suitable for 5.0.1.

Adt won't be update any more,so suggest you using AndroidStudio.